# Running node app from a different directory makes static folder act funny

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

Here's the gist of my project structure:

- /

  - node_modules/
  - public/

    - css/

      - main.css
  - server/

    - views/
    - app.js
  - package.json

Here's my super simple app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/public', express.static('public'));


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('live at http://localhost:3000');
});
```

**Now**, when I am in the root directory, run `node server.app.js` and load up the url `http://localhost:3000/public/css/main.css` everything loads perfectly as expected.

**However**, when I am in the server/ directory, run `node app.js`, and load up the same url, I get the error `Cannot GET /public/css/main.css`.

Is there a way for me to fix this so I can run my project from any directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
```

with this:

```
var path = require('path');

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));
```

The problem with the first snippet is that `'public'` is interpreted as relative to the current working directory. With the second snippet, it's relative to the location of `app.js` - which isn't dependent upon your current working directory.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Works perfectly. Is there any way to do this without `path`? If this is the quickest way, that's fine though.

Comment: You don't have to use `path`. I just prefer using `join` to avoid dealing with trailing and leading slashes, etc. Anyway, it's only called once, so there is nothing to optimize with the usage in the snippet.